# How to use Count(*) in JPQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a JPQL subquery in which I want to return a list of customerIds that meet a specific condition based on a ManyToOne relationship as shown below:

```
SELECT c.customerId
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN FETCH c.customersChild cc
LEFT JOIN FETCH c.childsPet cp on cp.name = 'Rover'
GROUP BY c.customerId
HAVING (COUNT(cp.name) / COUNT(*)) = 1
```

In this case, the customer should only be present in the list if all of their childrens' pet's names are Rover. The `HAVING (COUNT(cp.name) / COUNT(*)) = 1` clause works as-is in Oracle (SQL), since `COUNT(cp.name)` counts the number of non-null rows for each customer, and `COUNT(*)` counts the total number of rows (including nulls present due to the left join) for each customer... I believe `COUNT(cp.name)` works in JPQL but it doesn't seem like there is equivalent for `COUNT(*)`... does anyone know if there is a way to count all the rows within a group including nulls?

Comment: `count(1)` should work

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you rewrite your query to the more understandable anti-join variant:

```sql
SELECT c.customerId
FROM Customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM c.customersChild cc
  JOIN cc.childsPet cp
  WHERE cp.name = 'Rover'
)
```